# Many-to-one mapping of user threads to a kernel thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, linux-kernel, operating-system

As I understand it, in many-to-one mapping, one kernel thread manages many user threads. This kernel thread helps the user threads make system calls etc. What I don't understand is:

1. Why do we have many-to-one mapping if a single blocking call would
   block all user threads managed by the kernel thread ?
2. In many-to-one mapping of user threads to a kernel thread, do all the
   user threads have to be from the same process ?
3. In many-to-one mapping, can all the user threads be run on different
   cores/CPUs at once or is only one of them run at a time ?

Comment: What's wrong with googling? E.g., [fourth reference](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/4_Threads.html): `if a blocking system call is made, then the entire process blocks`, `Because a single kernel thread can operate only on a single CPU, the many-to-one model does not allow individual processes to be split across multiple CPUs`.

Comment: Before down voting the question, I would suggest you read all the sub questions to make sure you have answers of all of them somewhere on google or elsewhere. FYI, I couldn't find them on Google thus posted here. Also, the sub questions are somewhat related.

Comment: Actually, [reference](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/4_Threads.html) I have provided contains answers to all your questions: 1. `Thread management is handled by the thread library in user space, which is very efficient.`. 2. `multi-threaded applications have multiple threads within a single process, each having their own program counter...` 3. `Because a single kernel thread can operate only on a single CPU...`. Yes, level of details differs for different questions, but this is because you have several of them at once.

Comment: As you have tried to google, you have certainly seen some info about your questions. If you haven't understood this info, it could be better to *qoute* it in your question post and ask **what exactly you have failed to understand**. Such way you could explicitely **show your efforts**, so it would be no reason for downvoting. Also, such way you could get **more detailed answer**.

Comment: Googling the answer is useless - that's what all the other students have done.

Comment: @MartinJames Easy to believe that only "students" who do their home work ask such questions right ? Well, I am not a student who asked this question for my homework and I genuinely tried getting answers else where and SO before I asked here.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are correct that I should frame my question in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Why do we have many-to-one mapping if a single blocking call would
>   block all user threads managed by the kernel thread?

The drawback of having one-to-one mapping is involvement of kernel when there is a context switch between the threads. Involvement of kernel results in several overheads.

> 2)In many-to-one mapping of user threads to a kernel thread, do all
>   the user threads have to be from the same process?

Yes

> 3)In many-to-one mapping, can all the user threads be run on different
>   cores/CPUs at once or is only one of them run at a time?

The pro feature of having a many-one mapping is that entire thread context-switching is maintained by the user-level thread library you use and as far as kernel is concerned it doesn't know how many threads you have it gives the process a time slice to execute and it's up to the thread library to give control to any of the threads. From this, you can easily see that in many-to-one mapping at any instant only one thread of the process can get the control.

Comment: This question comes up about once a month.   It's a 'do all my assignment for me' :(

Comment: Clears all my doubts. Thank you.